# Safari keeps suggesting me top domain

Tags: safari, url, auto-complete

I have a website in the following format:

```
https://abc.def.com/subdomain1/subdomain2
```

But Safari keeps suggesting `https://abc.def.com` as a top hit, while the correct url is second. Now every time I need to select the second one, and since I visit this url a lot, it really frustrate me a lot.

I tried already to remove any record of `https://abc.def.com` in the history, but it doesn't work. Safari keeps on adding the top domain (abc.def.com only) as a top suggestion. I also removed everything in the history from this website, and then visited the correct url, and after that, big disappointment!